# How to pass a string value to K object in kdb+

Tags: c++, c, kdb

These days I written a C++ interface to be called by kdb+. In my cpp file, I define my function as follows:

```
 enter extern "C" K printInfo(K firstName, K secondName, K age)
 {
    if (firstName->t != -KS || secondName->t != -KS || age->t != -KJ) {
      printf("Invalid params\n");
      return krr("Invalid params");
   }

  printf("firstName:%s\tsecondName:%s\tage:%ld", firstName->s, secondName->s, age->j);
  return (K)0;
 }
```

After I compiled it to a dll, I write q script file to call it. The code as followed:

```
/ from the DLL mymoving load the functions and assign to named variables
/ The 2: is used for loading
/ 3 at the end specifies the number of arguments
printInfo:`myPrint 2:(`printInfo;3)
printInfo["yunfeng";"zhou";23]
/ printInfo[`yunfeng;`zhou;23]
```

However, It did not work. I tried google and the [kx](http://kx.com) web side to solve this problem, all I did in vain.

Comment: can you elaborate of "did not work"? any error messages or symptoms at all?

Comment: Can you not just cast string to symbols? your c++ code is expecting symbols, not strings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine if you pass names as symbols.  If you want to allow character vectors, you should allow `firstName->t == 10` and the same for the `secondName` when you check argument types.  Furthermore, you cannot use `->s` to access the character vector data.  You need to use `->n` to find the number of characters and `kC()` to get the pointer to the first character.  Note that character vectors (unlike symbols) are not null-terminated, so you cannot use C functions that expect pointers to null-terminated strings on the pointers returned by `kC()`.